# h:selectOneMenu required="true" reverts to bean value on validation failure

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have something like this on a create/edit form:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" required="true" ... >
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select --" itemValue=""/>
  <f:selectItems .../>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In the create new object case, the `required` validation works as expected.

In the edit object case, if I change a valid value to the placeholder "-- Select --", I get the validation failure w/expected requiredMessage because itemValue is blank (""); *however*, the HTML `<select>` reverts to whatever option was already selected from the bean, rather than retaining the invalid user input from form submission.

To reiterate, the `required=true` on the `h:selectOneMenu` itself works fine, generating the expected message - the only thing that's wrong is the value reverting to the bean value, instead of retaining the blank submitted value.  (I confirmed with Chrome developer toolbar that an empty string is indeed being POSTed for the `<select>`.)

Why is this happening?  More precisely, why is `h:selectOneMenu` not behaving like `h:inputText`, where the UIInput displays the invalid user input from the form, and does not refresh its value from the bean?  Both of these controls extend the same UIInput base class and implement EditableValueHolder, so I expect their lifecycle would behave the same.

Also, to clarify, I do not have the `INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` context param anywhere in web.xml.

This is a JSF application on Mojarra 2.1.3 / Glassfish 3.1.1.

Comment: First this, do you have `INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` context param set to `true` in your `web.xml`?

Comment: @BalusC - no, I didn't have that context param set.  Adding it actually had the opposite effect:  `h:inputText` with `required="true"` would not display the blank value from the form submission, and instead would revert to the value in the bean.

Comment: could it be a defect?  http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-932

Comment: Just updated JAVASERVERFACES-932 with comment showing impacted part of `MenuRenderer.java`

Comment: I'm not able to login in  java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-932. There is any correction path to this behavior?