# JSF 2.1 "required" atttribute and INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL and SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, el, mojarra

I am using Mojarra 2.1.5 (from weblogic 12c).

Firstly, I don't need to set `INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` and the "required" validation still works. This contradicts with this post: [h:inputText which is bound to String property is submitting empty string instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203322/hinputtext-return-a-empty-string-instead-of-null).

Can someone clarify what is going on?

Secondly, I am experiencing the same behavior as [h:selectOneMenu required="true" reverts to bean value on validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351326/hselectonemenu-required-true-reverts-to-bean-value-on-validation-failure).  I firmly believe this is a bug. But to provide more information, the value redisplayed is not coming from bean (in my test case I have a request scoped bean, so all attributes will be null), I believe is from the `UIComponent.getValue()` which is retained from the previous life cycle instead of `UIComponent.getSubmittedValue()`.

Can anyone confirm this?